# why can't we use Integer.parseInt(args[0]) instead of Scanner

Tags: java

When I used `Scanner` its running fine but I used `Integer.parseInt(args[0])` there is an error.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter col ");
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();  
        for (int i = 1;i<= row; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
                System.out.print("B");      
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch( NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println();
```

By using `Integer.parseInt()` there is error. I don't understand `Integer.parseInt(args[0])` also converting into integer.

```
try{

    for (int i = 1;i<= Integer.parseInt(args[0]); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= Integer.parseInt(args[1]; j++) {
            System.out.print("B");      

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} catch( NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: These code snippets are doing fundamentally different things - you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: what error does this code throws?

Comment: Because scanner reads `System.in`, while `args[0]` does not (it's your program's initial run-time argument).

Comment: To answer the question in your title, you can! You can use it for reading the first command line argument, provided there is one and it conforms to the syntax of an `int`.

Comment: it throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Problems.Trangle.main(Trangle.java:109)

Answer (score 0):

args[] contains the arguments you give to your program when launching it (usually after calling it on the console)

Did you give arguments to your program ?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your second code snippet into the `main` method of a newly created class. Fixed a simple typo (there’s a right bracket missing). The I ran the class from my command prompt (shell) this way:

```
java com.stackoverflow.richaojha.parseargs.ArgsParseIntDemo 2 3
```

Output was:

```
BBB
BBB
```

You notice that it reads the numbers 2 and 3 nicely from the command line. So if this is what you want, you can. It is something different from reading from standard input, as your first snippet does, of course.

Comment: But i am getting thisException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Problems.Trangle.main(Trangle.java:109)

Comment: That sounds like it’s because you aren’t providing any command line arguments like I did on the command line in the answer. When you don’t, `main()` will receive an `args` array of length 0, so already when you try to take element 0 out of it, you’re outside the array and get that exception.

Comment: If you are running your program from your IDE, there is bound to be a way to provide command line arguments too. The way to do varies by IDE (it will be different in Eclipse from how it is in IntelliJ IDEA or Netbeans).